# How can I convert the data from Polygon to lat, lng

Tags: geolocation, polygon, latitude-longitude, geo, utm

image below is the data that I have and I do not know what is the type of coordinates! I thought it was `UTM` but it is not!

Can you please help me to understand the type and the way of converting it to the `lat` and `lng`?!

[image]

Comment: These numbers are too small for UTM. Is it [Belgian Lambert 1972](http://epsg.io/31370)? The best way to resolve this is to ask the data provider, if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the provider!